# How to pass the object to function call from javascript as href

Tags: javascript

Using inline events as attributes I can pass the current object to a function using `this` keyword. How could I do it using calling it through Javascript as href.

The following example clearing the question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script>
function foo(ob){
  alert(ob.innerText);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <a href="#" onclick="foo(this)">On Click Call</a> Works Fine!
   <br />
   <br />
   <a href="javascript:foo(this)">Javascript linked</a> Does not work.
</body>
</html>
```

Checkout this [**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/kunero/1/)

Comment: Why do you want to put it in the href instead of the onclick?

Comment: To be compatible with any event on any device. For example, suppose, you have made focus on the link using tab and pressed Enter

Comment: The `onclick` handler is still called when you focus on the link using tab and press Enter.  I just verified that here in the major browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4o2Lakf4/

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh! thank you for this updating information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, for maintainability reasons among others, it's a good idea to avoid putting JavaScript directly into the `href` attribute. So I would not recommend this approach. However, if you did need to go this route for some reason...

When JavaScript is invoked via the `href` attribute, the value of `this` is `window`. To get the clicked element instead, one (somewhat kludgy) solution is to assign it an `id` attribute that you can use to select it.

```
<a id="js-linked" href="javascript:foo(document.getElementById('js-linked'));">Javascript linked</a>
```

As you can see, this gets a little hard to read. Using the `onclick` attribute keeps things cleaner and more maintainable because `this` is assigned the value of the clicked element. And avoiding inline JS altogether and attaching a `click` listener in isolated code might keep things cleaner and more maintainable yet.

Comment: Why in the world is this a recommended solution?

Comment: @jfriend00 I +1'd because it answered the OP's question. I +1'd your answer because it's the recommended solution in general

Comment: It's my opinion that we should understand what the OP is trying to accomplish and offer the best solution to that problem.  That often means recommending a solution that is not exactly what the OP asked for because way too many questions have the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where they ask about their solution rather than ask for the best solution to the problem.  As such, I don't literally "answer the question asked" when there is a much better solution to the actual problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 I share that opinion. However, that's not how votes are supposed to be cast according to SO guidelines.

Comment: @CrayonViolent - uhhh, votes should be provided to good answers.  If you think providing an ugly solution is a good answer, then I guess it's your prerogative to upvote that.  I don't upvote answers that are not good, recommended code.

Comment: @jfriend00 The OP did not ask for a better method to hook into click events. He asked why it didn't work as he thought it would in an `href` attribute.  Your solution is the better solution for tapping into click events, for sure. Nobody is arguing that. **But it does not answer the question posed by OP**.

Comment: @CrayonViolent - The OP wants to solve a problem.  I offered what I thought was the best way to solve that problem.  It is a different direction than the OP was headed, but is a better way to solve the problem they had.  I think that understanding the actual problem the OP has and providing the best solution to that problem creates a more valuable answer that teaches the OP how to both solve their problem and write better code.  I would hope that upvoters recognize the value of "better solutions" too, but I don't get to influence that.

Comment: Look man, I get what you're saying and I agree. I've been in your shoes. But I've also been in OP's shoes. I ask a question about why something doesn't work and while I am grateful and will almost certainly make use of alternative, better solutions, I still want to know why the thing I did didn't work.  So when I post a question asking "why doesn't this work?" I'm going to liberally and gratefully hand out upvotes to the people like you who offer better alts, but I'm going to give the solve to the person who actually answers the question.  There's really nothing more to say about it.

Comment: @CrayonViolent - if the OP wants to know something beyond what my answer offers, they are free to ask in a comment.  If they disagree that my answer is a better way to solve their problem, they are free to accept a different answer.  And, when I see answers (even if they answer the literal question) that are a bad way to write code, I will comment on those answers too because I think it's a disservice in general to recommend bad techniques, even if they answer the literal question.  I think we've both said our piece so I'll go back to answering other questions.

Answer (score 3):

It's generally better to use the principles of [Unobstrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and not put the event handler in your HTML at all.

When you then use `.addEventListener()` to install your event handler, the value of `this` will be set for you automatically to the object that caused the event.

Here's how that would work:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
   <a href="#" id="call">On Click Call</a> Works Fine!
<script>
document.getElementById("call").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(this.textContent);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Changes made:

1. Move the `<script>` tag to after the content so DOM elements will already be loaded when the script runs.
2. Add a unique id value to the target link
3. Use `document.getElementById()` to get the target link object
4. Move the event handler out of your HTML and into your script and use `.addEventListener()` to add the event handler.
5. Use `this` to refer to the clicked link in the event handler.

Comment: I have read `Unobstrusive Javascript` document that you regarde above and it did not incline me to think that using inline events or Javascript as href is not good behavior, because HTML5 tags include more and complicated attributes rather than simple an inline event with a little function name as its value.

Comment: @sємsєм - Here's another link on the topic: [W3: The Princicples of Unobtrusive Javascript](http://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript).  For me, the main idea is that content and code are separate types of resources, often worked on by different teams in the company and often managed differently.  Thus, it is better to not intertwine Javascript inside the HTML content.  This is a widely accepted design pattern.

Comment: Ok, I +1 to your answer because the mention of this concept, but I have to accept the other answer because it offers the specific answer to my question itself. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

In the `javascript:foo(this)` `this` refers to Window object. You do not have a reference to the clicked element when using javascript pseudo protocol, therefore it will not work.